# Java Kafka consumer group failing to consume a few messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka

One issue is noticed that wherein Kafka consumer group (implemented in java) misses a few message from broker consistently. As a first line of debugging, via kafka console consumer, I can see those messages available in the broker.

Kafka broker version: 0.10.1.0

Kafka client version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Kafka consumer configuration:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers","broker1,broker2,broker3");
props.put("group.id", "myGroupIdForDemo");
props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", "25000"); 
props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000"); 
props.put("max.poll.interval.ms", "300000");
props.put("max.poll.records", "1");
props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "120000");
props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "10000");
props.put("auto.commit.enable", "false");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "60000");
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
props.put("consumer.timeout.ms", "-1");
props.put("rebalance.max.retries", "20");
props.put("rebalance.backoff.ms", "6000");

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
```

**EDIT - Addition of some more information**

Some more info I would like to add:
There are total 6 partitions. However, total number of consumers are 40 for the topic having the same consumer group id. I do understand that 34 consumers sit idle and do nothing.

However, the aspect I would like to understand is, if a consumer fails to send heartbeat to the extent that broker considers as dead and reassigns the partition, will any of the idle consumer get a chance to consume message ? This issue of message being not consumed is always being noticed in certain partitions only. I mean messages are failed to be delivered/consumed from the same partition.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: does it miss first / last / random messages?

Comment: Is there any other process/thread running with `myGroupIdForDemo`? Does the behaviour persist, if you assign it a random value?

Comment: @Natalia, it is random messages.

Comment: @SzymonBiliński, yes, since it is a consumer group, a few other consumers with the same group id is running as well.

Comment: @thomas To be more precise: in this "debugging scenario", are you sure that the message wasn't processed by a different consumer running with the same consumer group id?

Comment: @SzymonBiliński, yes I have checked, the message was delivered to none of the consumers of the consumer group myGroupIdForDemo.

Answer (score 5):

a) message may not exist even in Kafka - in that case check if message size does not exceed the max message size allowed in the kafka broker configs.

b) if your consumer connected to Kafka instance 1 and 2-d instance is not connected, you may miss messages from the 2-d kafka: so , specify all brokers in the consumer connection string.

3) if message exists on the kafka and you connected, you may fail to deserialize the message, so, try another deserializer, may be not string, but bytearray one and see what happens, will message be consumed? If yes, conversion to string is problematic.

4) message could be "stolen" by another working consumer , working under the same group ID, choose unique group id.

5) 
what logger you use to see consumed message? do not you suspect it is a logger issue?

6)
May be you kill/stop consumer, before it consumes all messages?

7)
May be you consume, but fail because of consumer memory limits? Mey be increase -Xmx. (heap size)

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, none of the seven points hold true. However, what I suspect is when partition reassignment happens (due to one of the consumer delays in sending heartbeat to the broker), then something is happening which I need to understand.

Comment: In described case the consumer can disconnect and so rebalance happens. 

You need prevent consumer disconnect. I suspect your consumer heratbeat fails for a reason: some message simply kills your consumer. May be message size, may be deserializer error, something..

Comment: thanks for the response. There is no error however processing of some messages takes time; processing is I/O bound operations viz. looking up in DB, interacting with other services etc. and that is causing the rebalance. Do you think if I could manage sending the heartbeat to avoid rebalance will solve the issue ?

Comment: I think setting very long session.timeout.ms may help you